# How to query a specific list of indexes in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating the date based elastic indexes like - logs-2017-06-10, logs-2018-07-10, logs-2019-06-11, date suffix can be any valid date.

How can i limit my search query to only search against specific days index.

for example if i want to seach between 2018-06-09 to 2018-06-11 then only below mentioned indexes should get searched against my query

`logs-2018-06-09, logs-2018-06-10 and logs-2018-06-11`

I tried wildcard * but it will not help here.

`logs-2018-06-*` will search in indexes `logs-2018-06-01 to logs-2018-06-30` which is not my query.

how can i only limit it to 
`logs-2018-06-09,logs-2018-06-10 and logs-2018-06-11`

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "indices" : {
            "indices" : ["index1", "index2"],
            "query" : { "term" : { "tag" : "wow" } },
            "no_match_query" : { "term" : { "tag" : "kow" } }
        }
    }
}
```

From: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-indices-query.html

Comment: This solution will not be applicable in my case, as I need to search against a dynamic list of indexes, not the static list.

Comment: I did not find any way to decide the dynamic list of indices against which I could run my search query.

As an alternative now I will run my search query against all the indices and based on date range query.

GET logs-2019-*/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "timestamp" : {
                "time_zone": "+01:00", 
                "gte": "2015-01-01 00:00:00", 
                "lte": "now" 
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any way to decide the dynamic list of indices against which I could run my search query.

As an alternative now I will run my search query against all the indices and based on date range query.

````
GET logs-2019-*/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "timestamp" : {
                "time_zone": "+01:00", 
                "gte": "2015-01-01 00:00:00", 
                "lte": "now" 
            }
        }
    }
}```
````